# Paypal Here Sandbox merchant account setup for Android SDK

Tags: android, paypal, sdk, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to setup a merchant on Sandbox to use for the Android Paypal Here SDK in a custom build app.

I followed the documentation and generated an authorization code for the merchant when it granted permission to my Paypal REST API app.

Now I need to generate a refresh token for my merchant. According to my research and the Sample server I need to use the auth code to get a refresh token and access tokens.

My problem is that when I do this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic <base64<myclientid:mysecret>>" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=<myauth_code>' "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/tokenservice"
```

I get the following response even though I supplied a base64 Basic auth header for clientId:secret

```
{
  "error_description": "client id or secret is null",
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "correlation_id": "2166d2191a0ad",
  "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This was happening for an app I created. However when using the client id for the app that was created when I signed up, it worked fine. 
So the problem lies not in the code, but in the setup somewhere in PayPal Developer

Comment: did you worked on Paypal here sdk